# Authcode for Alexa BDD Tests using LWA

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, automation, aws-sdk, alexa-skills-kit

During Accountlinking, Alexa server initiates a Acceptgrant API with its Authcode so that it can be exchanged to Access Token. I want to test my API which accepts the Authcode
(postman or BDD Tests). How can we generate this ?  It would be really helpful for automated tests.

I have tried LWA with AWS JS SDK. We need to whitelist the server in security profile. This basically opens a browser instance and appends a Authcode to the redirect_uri. Is there any other way than this? I read about CLI where we can get accesstoken but not authcode.

Also when we create a skill it generates a ClientId. Are there any security profiles for this ClientId ? How can I whitelist my server for this ClientId ? I didnt find a way to link this client ID to security profile.

Some more info:
I will elaborate a bit more. Basically Alexa sends a AcceptGrant directive during account linking when user enables the skill from alexa UI. AcceptGrant consists of Authcode so that User/bussiness(smart device manufacturer cloud) can get accesstoken using LWA. So now the bussiness has API exposed which accepts a Authcode. Now i am trying to test this API. Currently i dont find a way to generate this token.

If i generate authcode with LWA flow , this requires a redirect_uri. But if i use the code which is sent by Alexa (during accountlinking flow) , it doesn't require redirect_uri. From this page

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/authorization-code-grant.html#access-token-request

if i use AWS JS SDK it doesnt require a redirect_uri for access_token request. When i tried AWS JS to generate authcode, i get an secuirty error asking user to whitelist the domain. And i dont find a way to whitelist the client_id of Alexa to a security profile.

Answer (score 0):

In skill linking, linking out from a skill to a 3p server, Alexa handles the auth code exchange and retrieves the access token for you. The auth code is never exposed to the skill because you don't need it.

It's only good once. After that, you use the refresh token returned when the auth code was used.

Maybe if you describe the use case you're trying to accomplish and why you believe you need the code, it'll be possible to give you more useful help.

Comment: Added more info in the question .